# Write-through buffer in WCF

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0

Is there any standard way of implementing some sort of a write-through buffer for a WCF call? I need a mechanism to be able to write to a bufffer or cache which gets persisted and then writes it to the service. If the service is down the call will be transfered when the service is up and running again. I know you can use WCF over MSMQ which does exactly what I need, but I wounder if there is another way of doing this, so I don't need to deploy MSMQ to the client.

Best regards,
Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that MSMQ is designed to do this - if you want to do this without MSMQ then you must implement your own queuing mechanism that functions like MSMQ and deploy that to the client.